# react-native link failing with expo project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a React-Native project which I generated using `expo init`. That doesn't give you an `ios`/`android` folder like `create-react-native-app` used to do.

I installed this package: https://github.com/zhangtaii/react-native-google-place-picker

And upon trying to use `react-native link`, I get the following error:

```
Checking Podfile in iOS project (/Users/<path>/ios/Podfile)
Adding Podfile to iOS project
node_modules/react-native-google-place-picker/bin/cocoapods.sh: line 38: cd: ios: No such file or directory
node_modules/react-native-google-place-picker/bin/cocoapods.sh: line 40: /Users/<path>/ios/Podfile: No such file or directory
Installing Pods
[!] `/Users/<name>/<folder>/ios` is not a valid directory.
/Users/<path>/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/core/makeCommand.js:27
        throw new Error(`Error occurred during executing "${command}" command`);
        ^

Error: Error occurred during executing "node_modules/react-native-google-place-picker/bin/cocoapods.sh" command
```

Under the new expo setup, do you still need to `react-native link` or is that all automatic now?

Answer (score 1):

When you use react-expo-cli in order to generate either android or ios you need to run npm eject. Afterwards you could build with npm run android or ios whichever the case.
Practically the error is telling that ios folder doesn't exists, so need to create it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unforutently, you can't use native modules in expo.io which means link will not work.

You may want to consider ejecting your project from expo and using expokit instead. 
Most of the expo features will still be available to you with the exception of Push Notifications and you will be able to use link. However, this could lead to other issues that are not related to expo.

See https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for "android" and "ios" folders using Expo for a react-native project. Expo lets you write one code for both platforms.

And it seems like there is no `react-native link ...` in Expo